# Learning MySQli CRUD nothing happen when delete record

Tags: php, mysqli

i was suggested to learn PHP using mysqli because the book i have read is too old. People always say mysql is deprecated. now I am learning again using new syntax mysqli. this is my reference for learning :

http://www.w3programmers.com/crud-with-php-and-mysqli-using-oop-syntax/

Add php success and the code worked as explained -

Display php success and the code worked as explained -

edit php sucess and the code worked as explained -

but why when i click delete on display php nothing happen :'(

[image]

```
//just preparing the edit link to edit the record
echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$id}'>Edit</a>";
echo " / ";

//just preparing the delete link to delete the record
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

i think the problem is in the above code, but i cant fix it..

would be grateful :') if anybody could correct this problem and explain why delete.php is not working?
Thanks

Comment: we don't see any references

Comment: dear, i was update the information above.

Comment: Check this tutoral : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satyapriyanayak/how-to-insert-edit-and-delete-in-php/ and you can download complete source from there once you have an account.

Comment: that code is not enough please provide us with the js delete_user function

Comment: maybe this code? 

<script type='text/javascript'>

function delete_user( id ){

//prompt the user

var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');

if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok

//redirect to url with action as delete and id of the record to be deleted

window.location = 'delete.php?action=delete&amp;id=' + id;

}

}

</script>

Comment: Dear ullas mohan, thanks i will check.